# Determine if a hotfix has been applied to a machine using .NET

Tags: .net, hotfix

Is it possible to use the .net framework (v4.0) to determine if particular hotfix is made to machine?  I've not come across any information on this so far.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows hotfix?  You can check for the hotfix in the Registry (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238552) using a call like

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\HotFix\KB2121546", "Valid", 0);
```